# When I display the UIImagePickerController in a UIPopupviewController, it crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I have in a UIpopupviewController a call to the IOS camera, sometimes i can take more that 2 pictures sometime after the first call it crash.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (image, nil, nil , nil);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

}

-(IBAction)takephoto:(id)sender {

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        imagePicker.delegate=self;
        imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing=NO;
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:NO];

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `presentModalViewController`and `dismissModalViewController` are deprecated as of iOS 6.0. Try to replace them with `presentViewController:animated:` after setting `modalPresentationStyle` and `modalTransitionStyle` on the viewController you want to present as modal.

Comment: In your code, what is `self` ?

Comment: do you get a message for the crash?

Comment: this is the only message i got

**libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x3bbbd5a0:  teq.w  r0, #0
0x3bbbd5a4:  beq    0x3bbbd5e6                ; objc_msgSend + 70
0x3bbbd5a6:  push.w {r3, r4}
0x3bbbd5aa:  ldr    r4, [r0]
0x3bbbd5ac:  lsr.w  r9, r1, #2
0x3bbbd5b0:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8]
0x3bbbd5b2:  add.w  r3, r3, #8
0x3bbbd5b6:  ldr    r12, [r3, #-8]
0x3bbbd5ba:  and.w  r9, r9, r12
0x3bbbd5be:  ldr.w  r4, [r3, r9, lsl #2]**

Comment: @Radu i posted the exact bug i encountered right now second call to the camera crash the app

Comment: @Vinzzz i updated my code, it was called by a uipopovercontroller using storyboard

Comment: @Vinzzz I enable the NSZombie and i got this message 2013-07-25 14:02:24.668 TMS[10343:907] *** -[UIImagePickerController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x202c35a0

Comment: Can you try to make the imagePicker as a strong property?

Comment: I just tried now but it still crashed : 
Here is the message log
-[UIImagePickerController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1e4db020

Comment: `presentViewController:animated` shouldn't be called by some UIPopoverController, nor the UIViewController you put inside... On your screenschot, you seem to be calling `dismissViewControler:animated` on imagePicker parentViewController just after calling `presentViewController`, this seems funny

Comment: I'm sorry newbie here but the button to call the camera is inside the uiviewcontroller that was called via UIStoryboardPopoverSegue, how can i present it?